# Socket.io in user-to-user chat

Tags: javascript, php, socket.io, one-to-one

I'm trying to do a user-to-user webchat, it works with PHP/JS.

How it should works: Input the username (that's registered in the mysql database), and the user will be displayed below (its like an user connected list).
[Like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wx9O.png)

I did the code, but it's not working the user connected list that i made :(

PHP File (index)

```
io.on("user_connected", function (username) {

var html = "";
html += '<div class="chat_list" data-username="' + username + '" onclick="onUserSelected(this);">';
    html += '<div class="chat_people">';
        html += '<div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>';
        html += '<div class="chat_ib">';
          html += '<h5>' + username + '</h5>';
        html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';
document.getElementById("users").innerHTML += html; });
```

JS File (server)

```
var users = [];

io.on("connection", function (socket) {

console.log("User connected: ",  socket.id);

socket.on("user_connected", function (username) {
    users[username] = socket.id;
    io.emit("user_connected", username); });
```

Comment: Hey Matheus! Saying "it's not working" doesn't give us much information to help you, what in particular isn't working how you expect?

Comment: Sorry, the user connected list it's not working. When i input the user, it only gives me the message that i am connected to the chat, but the user doesn't appear in the list or in the console